# Unable to start program in debug mode. Debug Dll installation issue?

Tags: visual-studio-2005

I've just get a new machine and try to checkout, build  and launch my program.
When hitting "launch in debug" button, I have this error message poping up from MS VS:

> Unable to start program 'xx'. This
>   application has failed to start
>   because the application configuration
>   is incorrect. Reviex the manifest file
>   for possible errors. Reinstalling the
>   application may fix this problem. For
>   more details , please see the
>   application event log.

Have a look into the application event log:

> Type de l'événement : Erreur Source de
>   l'événement : SideBySide Catégorie de
>   l'événement : Aucun ID de l'événement
>   : 59 Date :       24/08/2009 Heure
>   :     16:10:03 Utilisateur :  N/A
>   Ordinateur :  XXXXXXXX Description :
>   Resolve Partial Assembly a échoué pour
>   Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT. Message
>   d'erreur de référence : L'assemblage
>   référencé n'est pas installé sur votre
>   système. .
>
> Pour plus d'informations, consultez le
>   centre Aide et support à l'adresse
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

Ok , the text is in french, but it roughly tells that that resolving the "partial assembly" didn't work for "Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT". It conludes so that this assemlby is not installed on my machine.

Having a look into the C:\windows\system32 folders, I see no mscvrt80d.dll file. (Huu .. Is it this one I should expect?). MS visual studio 8.0 is freshly installed by admin system though.

Did you ever have that issue before ? And how did you fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually CRT was not the issue here. What caused the problem was that another lib I used was compiled by a co-worker on his machine and sent to me through shared directory. Therefore the recipient folder for the DLL was not the same as it was on the original machine from my coleague. I guess the issue is because the manifest files expect it to be the same(?), or does it expect to find the source code at a specified path (?).

Anyway, re-compiling the lib in question from scratch on my machine resolved the issue..

Answer (score 1):

It is not the neatest solution, but in addition to shared SxS installs of the C-runtime - which incidentally are installed to a folder: c:\windows\winsxs - its completely legitimate to perform what is called a "private side-by-side" install - which for debug builds will be most convenient.

Simply go to your folder: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\x86, and copy the appropriate folder into the deployment folder of your debug build:

So, if your app is installed in C:\Test\MyApp, you would now have a folder called C:\Test\MyApp\Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT
(You can also copy the foles from the assembly straight into your app folder, but I find that messy).