# Prefetching information in windows XP fails and abort the launching of my application

Tags: prefetch, windows-xp-sp3, procmon, process-monitor

I compile my application on a windows XP SP3 machine. When it compiles, I try to lauch it, and windows replies me back with :

> Unable to start program 'xx'. This
>   application has failed to start
>   because the application configuration
>   is incorrect. Reviex the manifest file
>   for possible errors. Reinstalling the
>   application may fix this problem. For
>   more details , please see the
>   application event log.

Trying to copy DLL files didn't help (see [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322758/unable-to-start-program-in-debug-mode-debug-dll-installation-issue) if you want).

I've launch Process monitor from sysinternals then.
I try here to summarise the report while it is not very long.
The process starts, then its first thread. Following is calls to :
QueryNameInformationFile() of my exe file => *SUCCESS*
Load Image() of my exe file => *SUCCESS*
Load Image() of ntdll.dll   => *SUCCESS*
QueryNameInformationFile() if my exe file => *SUCCESS*
CreateFile() Try to create it un C:\WINDOWS\Prefetch\blahbla.pf => **NAME NOT FOUND**
then the thread and the process exits.

I've add my users with full control on that folder (C:\WINDOWS\prefetch), but did not help.
How to make it work? I feel if I go through this step, my application will work as expected.

Edit: I add procmon details about the error:

> 18:13:40,4305346  xxx.exe 3172    CreateFile  C:\WINDOWS\Prefetch\XXX.EXE-1FA9609A.pf NAME
>   NOT FOUND Desired Access: Generic
>   Read, Disposition: Open, Options:
>   Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Attributes:
>   n/a, ShareMode: None, AllocationSize:
>   n/a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is Task Scheduler running on the PC? A way to repair Prefetch is detailed here, if that is causing the problem :

http://members.rushmore.com/~jsky/id14.html

Comment: Yep, task schrduler is running. I don't think I need to repair my prefetch folder. I believe I need to tune my application's rights, or something like that. But I'll look at your advise in last case. Thanks.